# Kernel died restarting spyder and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I am experiencing a strange issue on my PyQt5 running on Python for Windows 10 64 bit. I am using Spyder as editor.

Below is my code

```
#read in a table from db
dbpath = r"c:\mypath\TransactionToday.db"
dbpath.replace('\\','/')
import sqlite3 as sql
conn = sql.connect(dbpath)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Bord_1_2127")
data = c.fetchall()
conn.close()
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import(QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem)
tw = QTableWidget()
tw.setRowCount(len(data))
tw.setColumnCount(4)
r = -1
c = -1
```

When I debug my code I see that the kernel died at

```
tw = QTableWidget()
```

I am not sure the reason why, as if I fresh restart my PC I can get it to work. However if I run this code multiple times, all of sudden I keep getting into the Kernel died restart issue. When I search on this issue I see multiple report on that this problem is related to Windows 10 and others mention that it is due to start up of too many instances of PyQt5. I am not sure if this is my case, since I guess my code is not starting up any instances related to QApplication?

Comment: IDK now, but prior to QT5, spyder was based on QT4 and I think you could not use QT4 with it; maybe it is the same sort of incompatibility?

Comment: But I am using Qt5 with Spyder

Comment: Please see [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder) for help. I think your main problem is that you're not even creating a Qt application to put your widget into it.